# How ADF Master Detail concept works internally?

Tags: oracle-adf, master-detail

I have used Master Detail concept in ADF with 2 pages. One will be the parent page. 2nd will be the child page.

Whatever we select in master page and navigate to the detail page, we are able to see the corresponding details. But how internally it works. Is there any concept like setRowCurrentKey with this? If so, where it is set in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - there is setcurrentrow concept in ADF - it persist the specific row selected between pages for you. ADF is a stateful solution that keeps that state across pages.
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/adf/develop/GUID-47BFAE1C-EF95-47C4-B92B-BEC385258F54.htm#GUID-833CF94C-C719-4C5A-9497-C4BDDDA93B79

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/adf/develop/GUID-AB535984-912A-47E9-9A3B-31BCA2C01F1A.htm#ADFFD19698